# Make a web service using Python to call Python script

Tags: python, web-services, python-2.7

I have a Python script that needs to be called to run via a web service. Is it possible to use Python to create a web service that triggers the Python script?

Any third party Python library can be recommended please?

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: circuits.web? http://circuitsweb.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [circuits.web](http://circuitsweb.com) for example (Use [circuits-dev](https://bitbucket.org/circuits/circuits-dev)

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import check_output


from circuits.web import Controller, Server


class Root(Controller):

    def index(self):
        return check_output("python hello.py", shell=True)


app = Server("0.0.0.0:5000")
Root().register(app)

app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. Can you please elaborate on the design of the "hello.py"? I would like to have something printed out on the browser when the script gets run successfully.

Comment: As your follow-question is very specific to circuits, it would be best to take this discussion elsewhere or post a different question. Email the circuits-users google groups list or join the #circuits channel on  FreeNode.